# « Celui/ceux/celle/celles/ceci/cela » utilisé pour « this/these/that/those »

Tags: pronoms, démonstratifs, comparaison-de-langues

- **Masculin** : Celui = *this*, Ceux = *these*
- **Féminin** : Celle = *this*, Celles = *these*
- **Neutre** : ceci/cela(= ça)

Mais :

- Celui/Celle = th**a**t/th**o**se aussi ?
- Le pronom neutre est-il utilisé pour le masculin et le féminin (les deux comme « *this* » en anglais) ?

Comment: What do you mean by neuter here? French has grammatical gender only masculine and feminine, but it opposes animates and inanimates for pronoun selection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dans le désordre :

### Le pronom neutre est-il utilisé pour le masculin et le féminin (les deux comme « this » en anglais) ?

Le français ne comporte pas de genre neutre, contrairement à l'anglais. Tout est soit masculin soit féminin.

« Celui » est un pronom de reprise pour un nom masculin, « celle » pour un nom féminin.
 « Ceci », « cela » et « ça » peuvent être utilisés pour les deux genres et pour reprendre des tournures qui n'ont pas réellement de genre.

Par exemple : « Tu as réussi ! C'est génial ! » → « c' » = « ça » = « (le fait que) tu as réussi »

#### Différence entre « ceci », « cela » et « ça »

Ces trois mots résultent de la contraction d'expressions :

- « ceci » est la contraction de « ce-ici » ;
- « cela » et « ça » sont deux contractions de « ce-là ».

Ces formes indiquent que « ceci » est proximal (il est plus indiqué pour pointer quelque chose de proche, que l'on peut pointer du doigt) et donc est plus proche de « *this* ». Par opposition, « cela/ça » est plutôt distal (pour parler de quelque chose dans la distance, lointain, que l'on ne peut pas voir d'où l'on est) et correspond donc mieux à « *that* ».

Dans le cas d'une utilisation neutre du point de vue de la distance, on utilisera plus volontiers « cela/ça ». Dans certains cas, cela peut correspondre à « *this* » ou « *it* » en anglais.

> ***It**/**That** hurts!*
>   **Ça** fait mal !

### Celui/celle = that/those aussi ?

La distinction qui existe entre *this*/*these* et *that*/*those* est assez difficile à apprendre pour un français débutant en anglais car elle n'existe pas réellement en français.

Pour répondre en un mot à ta question : oui.

### Pour résumer :

- Masculin :

  - celui = *this*/*that*
  - ceux = *these*/*those*
- Féminin :

  - celle = *this*/*that*
  - celles = *these*/*those*
- « Neutre » :

  - ceci = *this*/*it*
  - cela, ça = (*this*/*it*/)*that*

Comment: Je pense que **ceci** correspond mieux à **this**, tandis que **cela** correspond mieux à **that**. N'y a-t-il pas une notion de distance avec l'objet ? Je pense au moment où on pointe un objet du doigt, je vais dire **ceci** s'il est proche de moi, ou **cela** s'il est loin... n'est-ce pas la même chose avec **this** / **that** ?

Comment: @Random Dans l'absolu, tu as raison (ceci = ce-ici, cela = ça = ce-là). Dans les faits, il est vrai que _ceci_ est utilisé à titre de _this_ presque exclusivement. _Cela/ça_ en revanche est utilisé de façon assez neutre (« Ça fait mal ! » désigne un événement proche). Je vais ajouter une note à ce sujet. Merci pour ta remarque.

Answer (score 4):

En français, celui/celle ne contient pas la nuance que l'on retrouve dans this/that en anglais. Il est toutefois possible d'apporter cette nuance à l'aide de ci (proximité) et là (éloignement), même si elle est moins importante qu'en anglais.

Pour les pronoms :

THIS : Celui-ci, celle-ci
THESE : ceux-ci, celles-ci

THAT : Celui-là, celle-là
THOSE : ceux-là, celles-là

Pour les déterminants (ce/cette/ces/cet), ci et là se placent après le nom

THIS dog : Ce chien-ci

THAT dog : Ce chien-là